# MYSQL: how to replace strings with REGEXP

Tags: mysql

I have one wordpress site, and in my posts , there are many contents which include `http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/`

I already run well the below query:

```
SELECT id,post_title,post_content
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_content REGEXP 'http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/'
```

But, my problem is not select, but replacing, as you know, replace can not directly use RegEx.

So how can I replace all `http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/` to empty in my all posts?

It should be like

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content, "http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/", "")
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your strings actually contain the literals "[0-9]+" ?  That is unusual.  What are some examples of real values in the data and what do you want to replace them with?

Comment: [0-9]+ means some posts may have `http://web.archive.org/web/12344/`, some posts may have `http://web.archive.org/web/9423743/`, or `http://web.archive.org/web/500243459354355/`  and so on ....

Comment: but may they have anything AFTER the `[0-9]+/` ? or is that the end of the string? or before the the `http://` ...?

Comment: yes, almost full string should like :  `http://web.archive.org/web/12344/http://someurl.com`,  so i want to replace  `http://web.archive.org/web/12344/http://someurl.com` to  `http://someurl.com`

Comment: but there is also the possibility of text in front of the first url? its important to know this. is there the possibility of there being another url, before the one you want to get rid of?

Comment: yes, content is a big text.  there are some url link in there.  i just want to replace all url which include `http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/`, that is it...

Comment: You'd be better off doing it with an application level script, using php or whatever. MySQL is not very well suited to that task at all

Answer (score 0):

How about looking for the `/http:`?  This may not work under *all* circumstances, but it might work on your data:

```
update wp_posts
    set post_content = substring_index(post_content, 'http:', -1)
    where post_content REGEXP '^http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/http:';
```

Answer (score 0):

anyways, I finished it using php

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    //$data[] = $row;

    $pattern      = "/http\:\/\/web\.archive\.org\/web\/[^\/]+\/http\:/i";
    $post_content = preg_replace($pattern, 'http:', $row['post_content']);

    echo mysql_query("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($post_content)."' WHERE ID = ".$row['ID']) ? $row['ID'].'<br>' : '<font color=red>'.$row['ID'].'</font><br>';

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the SELECT works then this simple modification should work as well

`UPDATE wp_posts
SETS post_content = ''
WHERE post_content REGEXP 'http://web.archive.org/web/[0-9]+/'`